# NS or SOA causing issues intermittently?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, ns-record, soa-record, amazon-lightsail

[My site](https://cloudconfusing.com) always seems to be loading fine for me but I started receiving reports of some people not being able to connect to the site. It seems to be a DNS issue, but I can't isolate the problem.

Some things I've seen:

- https://intodns.com/cloudconfusing.com
- [digwebinterface](https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=cloudconfusing.com&type=ANY&showcommand=on&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=)

Practical question: Both seem to be pointing to issues with the nameservers. Do my nameservers and SOA have to match? Should the nameservers I've gotten from my VPS provider (Lightsail) have to match the SOA at the registrar?

Academic question: Why is this working the vast majority of the time but not for everyone?

Thanks!

Comment: Your SOA is your Start Of Authority, meaning who is Authorizing this resolution, your Nameserver is a Name Server to be resolved

Comment: Those people with reports of errors, are they trying to access that exact domain name or are they trying to access https://domain/add/on an extension of the domain name

Comment: So zone is your domain name you want people to go to, your SOA is your Domain name inside of hosts which should be linked with your hostname, you should also be using resolvconf with a DNS, the last lines will start with either @, ., zone name or nothing, followed by the zone name in, as in @ IN NS 'nameserver to be resolved." Then @ IN A 192.168.1.XXX

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been a mismatch between the registrar NS and the hosted zone NS. Definitely an edge case, but it happened to affect some small number of visitors (<5%).